# Javascript Ownership Cost Calculator

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, html, calculator

Javascript newbie here. I built a total cost of ownership calculator to calculate the cost of a business over 5 years. It has a lot of repeating script and prob way more congested than it needs to be so I was wondering if y'all could give me an idea of how I could go about writing this in a more DRY way. Below is a live demo snippet of a portion of the calculator.

```js
/* Totals */

(function() {
  $('#1sfa1, #1sfa2, #1sfa3, #2sfa1, #2sfa2, #2sfa3, #3sfa1, #3sfa2, #3sfa3, #4sfa1, #4sfa2, #4sfa3, #5sfa1, #5sfa2, #5sfa3, #1sfm1, #1sfm2, #1sfm3, #2sfm1, #2sfm2, #2sfm3, #3sfm1, #3sfm2, #3sfm3, #4sfm1, #4sfm2, #4sfm3, #5sfm1, #5sfm2, #5sfm3, #1hcc1, #1hcq1, #1hcc2, #1hcq2, #1hcc3, #1hcq3, #1hcc4, #1hcq4, #1hcc5, #2hcq5, #2hcc1, #2hcq1, #2hcc2, #2hcq2, #2hcc3, #2hcq3, #2hcc4, #2hcq4, #2hcc5, #2hcq5, #3hcc1, #3hcq1, #3hcc2, #3hcq2, #3hcc3, #3hcq3, #3hcc4, #3hcq4, #3hcc5, #3hcq5, #4hcc1, #4hcq1, #4hcc2, #4hcq2, #4hcc3, #4hcq3, #4hcc4, #4hcq4, #4hcc5, #4hcq5, #5hcc1, #5hcq1, #5hcc2, #5hcq2, #5hcc3, #5hcq3, #5hcc4, #5hcq4, #5hcc5, #5hcq5, #1hc1, #1hc2, #1hc3, #1hc4, #1hc5, #2hc1, #2hc2, #2hc3, #2hc4, #2hc5, #3hc1, #3hc2, #3hc3, #3hc4, #3hc5, #4hc1, #4hc2, #4hc3, #4hc4, #4hc5, #5hc1, #5hc2, #5hc3, #5hc4, #5hc5').on('change keyup input', function() {

    /* ------- Subscription Fees ------- */
    sf1 = parseFloat($('#1sfa1').val()) + parseFloat($('#1sfa2').val()) + parseFloat($('#1sfa3').val());
    sf2 = parseFloat($('#2sfa1').val()) + parseFloat($('#2sfa2').val()) + parseFloat($('#2sfa3').val());
    sf3 = parseFloat($('#3sfa1').val()) + parseFloat($('#3sfa2').val()) + parseFloat($('#3sfa3').val());
    sf4 = parseFloat($('#4sfa1').val()) + parseFloat($('#4sfa2').val()) + parseFloat($('#4sfa3').val());
    sf5 = parseFloat($('#5sfa1').val()) + parseFloat($('#5sfa2').val()) + parseFloat($('#5sfa3').val());
    $('#sfTotal1').val(parseFloat(sf1).toFixed(2));
    $('#sfTotal2').val(parseFloat(sf2).toFixed(2));
    $('#sfTotal3').val(parseFloat(sf3).toFixed(2));
    $('#sfTotal4').val(parseFloat(sf4).toFixed(2));
    $('#sfTotal5').val(parseFloat(sf5).toFixed(2));

    /* ------- Hardware Costs ------- */
    hc1 = parseFloat($('#1hc1').val()) + parseFloat($('#1hc2').val()) + parseFloat($('#1hc3').val()) + parseFloat($('#1hc4').val());
    hc2 = parseFloat($('#2hc1').val()) + parseFloat($('#2hc2').val()) + parseFloat($('#2hc3').val()) + parseFloat($('#2hc4').val());
    hc3 = parseFloat($('#3hc1').val()) + parseFloat($('#3hc2').val()) + parseFloat($('#3hc3').val()) + parseFloat($('#3hc4').val());
    hc4 = parseFloat($('#4hc1').val()) + parseFloat($('#4hc2').val()) + parseFloat($('#4hc3').val()) + parseFloat($('#4hc4').val());
    hc5 = parseFloat($('#5hc1').val()) + parseFloat($('#5hc2').val()) + parseFloat($('#5hc3').val()) + parseFloat($('#5hc4').val());
    $('#hcTotal1').val(parseFloat(hc1).toFixed(2));
    $('#hcTotal2').val(parseFloat(hc2).toFixed(2));
    $('#hcTotal3').val(parseFloat(hc3).toFixed(2));
    $('#hcTotal4').val(parseFloat(hc4).toFixed(2));
    $('#hcTotal5').val(parseFloat(hc5).toFixed(2));
  });


  /* ------- Subscription Fees ------- */

  $('#1sfm1, #1sfm2, #1sfm3, #2sfm1, #2sfm2, #2sfm3, #3sfm1, #3sfm2, #3sfm3, #4sfm1, #4sfm2, #4sfm3, #5sfm1, #5sfm2, #5sfm3').on('input', function() {
    $('#1sfa1').val(parseFloat($('#1sfm1').val() * 12));
    $('#1sfa2').val(parseFloat($('#1sfm2').val() * 12));
    $('#1sfa3').val(parseFloat($('#1sfm3').val() * 12));
    $('#2sfa1').val(parseFloat($('#2sfm1').val() * 12));
    $('#2sfa2').val(parseFloat($('#2sfm2').val() * 12));
    $('#2sfa3').val(parseFloat($('#2sfm3').val() * 12));
    $('#3sfa1').val(parseFloat($('#3sfm1').val() * 12));
    $('#3sfa2').val(parseFloat($('#3sfm2').val() * 12));
    $('#3sfa3').val(parseFloat($('#3sfm3').val() * 12));
    $('#4sfa1').val(parseFloat($('#4sfm1').val() * 12));
    $('#4sfa2').val(parseFloat($('#4sfm2').val() * 12));
    $('#4sfa3').val(parseFloat($('#4sfm3').val() * 12));
    $('#5sfa1').val(parseFloat($('#5sfm1').val() * 12));
    $('#5sfa2').val(parseFloat($('#5sfm2').val() * 12));
    return $('#5sfa3').val(parseFloat($('#5sfm3').val() * 12));
  });

  $('#1sfa1, #1sfa2, #1sfa3, #2sfa1, #2sfa2, #2sfa3, #3sfa1, #3sfa2, #3sfa3, #4sfa1, #4sfa2, #4sfa3, #5sfa1, #5sfa2, #5sfa3').on('input', function() {
    $('#1sfm1').val(parseFloat($('#1sfa1').val() / 12));
    $('#1sfm2').val(parseFloat($('#1sfa2').val() / 12));
    $('#1sfm3').val(parseFloat($('#1sfa3').val() / 12));
    $('#2sfm1').val(parseFloat($('#2sfa1').val() / 12));
    $('#2sfm2').val(parseFloat($('#2sfa2').val() / 12));
    $('#2sfm3').val(parseFloat($('#2sfa3').val() / 12));
    $('#3sfm1').val(parseFloat($('#3sfa1').val() / 12));
    $('#3sfm2').val(parseFloat($('#3sfa2').val() / 12));
    $('#3sfm3').val(parseFloat($('#3sfa3').val() / 12));
    $('#4sfm1').val(parseFloat($('#4sfa1').val() / 12));
    $('#4sfm2').val(parseFloat($('#4sfa2').val() / 12));
    $('#4sfm3').val(parseFloat($('#4sfa3').val() / 12));
    $('#5sfm1').val(parseFloat($('#5sfa1').val() / 12));
    $('#5sfm2').val(parseFloat($('#5sfa2').val() / 12));
    return $('#5sfm3').val(parseFloat($('#5sfa3').val() / 12));
  });


  /* ------- Hardware Costs ------- */

  $('#1hcc1, #1hcq1, #1hcc2, #1hcq2, #1hcc3, #1hcq3, #1hcc4, #1hcq4, #1hcc5, #2hcq5, #2hcc1, #2hcq1, #2hcc2, #2hcq2, #2hcc3, #2hcq3, #2hcc4, #2hcq4, #2hcc5, #2hcq5, #3hcc1, #3hcq1, #3hcc2, #3hcq2, #3hcc3, #3hcq3, #3hcc4, #3hcq4, #3hcc5, #3hcq5, #4hcc1, #4hcq1, #4hcc2, #4hcq2, #4hcc3, #4hcq3, #4hcc4, #4hcq4, #4hcc5, #4hcq5, #5hcc1, #5hcq1, #5hcc2, #5hcq2, #5hcc3, #5hcq3, #5hcc4, #5hcq4, #5hcc5, #5hcq5').on('input', function() {
    $('#1hc1').val(parseFloat($('#1hcc1').val()) * (parseFloat($('#1hcq1').val())));
    $('#1hc2').val(parseFloat($('#1hcc2').val()) * (parseFloat($('#1hcq2').val())));
    $('#1hc3').val(parseFloat($('#1hcc3').val()) * (parseFloat($('#1hcq3').val())));
    $('#1hc4').val(parseFloat($('#1hcc4').val()) * (parseFloat($('#1hcq4').val())));
    $('#1hc5').val(parseFloat($('#1hcc5').val()) * (parseFloat($('#1hcq5').val())));
    $('#2hc1').val(parseFloat($('#2hcc1').val()) * (parseFloat($('#2hcq1').val())));
    $('#2hc2').val(parseFloat($('#2hcc2').val()) * (parseFloat($('#2hcq2').val())));
    $('#2hc3').val(parseFloat($('#2hcc3').val()) * (parseFloat($('#2hcq3').val())));
    $('#2hc4').val(parseFloat($('#2hcc4').val()) * (parseFloat($('#2hcq4').val())));
    $('#2hc5').val(parseFloat($('#2hcc5').val()) * (parseFloat($('#2hcq5').val())));
    $('#3hc1').val(parseFloat($('#3hcc1').val()) * (parseFloat($('#3hcq1').val())));
    $('#3hc2').val(parseFloat($('#3hcc2').val()) * (parseFloat($('#3hcq2').val())));
    $('#3hc3').val(parseFloat($('#3hcc3').val()) * (parseFloat($('#3hcq3').val())));
    $('#3hc4').val(parseFloat($('#3hcc4').val()) * (parseFloat($('#3hcq4').val())));
    $('#3hc5').val(parseFloat($('#3hcc5').val()) * (parseFloat($('#3hcq5').val())));
    $('#4hc1').val(parseFloat($('#4hcc1').val()) * (parseFloat($('#4hcq1').val())));
    $('#4hc2').val(parseFloat($('#4hcc2').val()) * (parseFloat($('#4hcq2').val())));
    $('#4hc3').val(parseFloat($('#4hcc3').val()) * (parseFloat($('#4hcq3').val())));
    $('#4hc4').val(parseFloat($('#4hcc4').val()) * (parseFloat($('#4hcq4').val())));
    $('#4hc5').val(parseFloat($('#4hcc5').val()) * (parseFloat($('#4hcq5').val())));
    $('#5hc1').val(parseFloat($('#5hcc1').val()) * (parseFloat($('#5hcq1').val())));
    $('#5hc2').val(parseFloat($('#5hcc2').val()) * (parseFloat($('#5hcq2').val())));
    $('#5hc3').val(parseFloat($('#5hcc3').val()) * (parseFloat($('#5hcq3').val())));
    $('#5hc4').val(parseFloat($('#5hcc4').val()) * (parseFloat($('#5hcq4').val())));
    return $('#5hc5').val(parseFloat($('#5hcc5').val()) * (parseFloat($('#5hcq5').val())));
  });
  
   /* ------- Total ------- */
    total = parseFloat(t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5).toFixed(2);
    return $('#TotalCost').val(total);

}).call(this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form id="msform">
        <fieldset id="table-two" class="table container-fluid">
          <div class="year1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2 class="fs-title">Subscription Fees</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="head2" class="head">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-3">
                    <h3>Monthly Fee</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-3">
                    <h3>Annual Spend</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <h4>Year 1</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>1st Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1sfm1" name="1sfm1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1sfa1" name="1sfa1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>2nd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1sfm2" name="1sfm2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1sfa2" name="1sfa2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>3rd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1sfm3" name="1sfm3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1sfa3" name="1sfm4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year2">
            <h4>Year 2</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>1st Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2sfm1" name="2sfm1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2sfa1" name="2sfa1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>2nd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2sfm2" name="2sfm2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2sfa2" name="2sfa2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>3rd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2sfm3" name="2sfm3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2sfa3" name="2sfa3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year3">
            <h4>Year 3</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>1st Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3sfm1" name="3sfm1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3sfa1" name="3sfa1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>2nd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3sfm2" name="3sfm2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3sfa2" name="3sfa2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>3rd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3sfm3" name="3sfm3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3sfa3" name="3sfa3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year4">
            <h4>Year 4</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>1st Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4sfm1" name="5sfm1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4sfa1" name="4sfa1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>2nd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4sfm2" name="4sfm2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4sfa2" name="4sfa2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>3rd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4sfm3" name="4sfm3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4sfa3" name="4sfa3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year5">
            <h4>Year 5</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>1st Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5sfm1" name="5sfm1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5sfa1" name="5sfa1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>2nd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5sfm2" name="5sfm2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5sfa2" name="5sfa2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>3rd Doctor</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5sfm3" name="5sfm3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <p>x12 mo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5sfa3" name="5sfa3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
 </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="table-three" class="table container-fluid">
          <div class="year1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2>Hardware Costs</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="head3" class="head">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-6">
                  <h3>Cost/Device</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
                  <h3>Quantity</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
                  <h3>Annual Spend</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <h4>Year 1</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcc1" name="1hcc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcq1" name="1hcq1" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hc1" name="1hc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>iPads</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcc2" name="1hcc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcq2" name="1hcq2" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hc2" name="1hc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Android Tablets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcc3" name="1hcc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcq3" name="1hcq3" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hc3" name="1hc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Servers</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcc4" name="1hcc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hcq4" name="1hcq4" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="1hc4" name="1hc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year2">
            <h4>Year 2</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcc1" name="2hcc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcq1" name="2hcq1" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hc1" name="2hc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>iPads</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcc2" name="2hcc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcq2" name="2hcq2" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hc2" name="2hc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Android Tablets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcc3" name="2hcc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcq3" name="2hcq3" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hc3" name="2hc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Servers</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcc4" name="2hcc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hcq4" name="2hcq4" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="2hc4" name="2hc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year3">
            <h4>Year 3</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcc1" name="3hcc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcq1" name="3hcq1" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hc1" name="3hc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>iPads</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcc2" name="3hcc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcq2" name="3hcq2" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hc2" name="3hc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Android Tablets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcc3" name="3hcc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcq3" name="3hcq3" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hc3" name="3hc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Servers</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcc4" name="3hcc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hcq4" name="3hcq4" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="3hc4" name="3hc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year4">
            <h4>Year 4</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcc1" name="4hcc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcq1" name="4hcq1" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hc1" name="4hc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>iPads</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcc2" name="4hcc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcq2" name="4hcq2" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hc2" name="4hc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Android Tablets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcc3" name="4hcc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcq3" name="4hcq3" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hc3" name="4hc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Servers</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcc4" name="4hcc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hcq4" name="4hcq4" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="4hc4" name="4hc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="year5">
            <h4>Year 5</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcc1" name="5hcc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcq1" name="5hcq1" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hc1" name="5hc1" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>iPads</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcc2" name="5hcc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcq2" name="5hcq2" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hc2" name="5hc2" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Android Tablets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcc3" name="5hcc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcq3" name="5hcq3" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hc3" name="5hc3" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
                <p>Servers</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcc4" name="5hcc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hcq4" name="5hcq4" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" id="5hc4" name="5hc4" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </fieldset>
        
        <fieldset id="table-seven" class="table container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2"> 
              <h3>Year 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <h3>Year 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"> 
              <h3>Year 3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <h3>Year 4</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <h3>Year 5</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <p>Subscription Fees</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="sfTotal1" name="sfTotal1" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="sfTotal2" name="sfTotal2" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="sfTotal3" name="sfTotal3" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="sfTotal4" name="sfTotal4" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="sfTotal5" name="sfTotal5" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <p>Hardware Costs</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="hcTotal1" name="hcTotal1" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="hcTotal2" name="hcTotal2" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="hcTotal3" name="hcTotal3" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="hcTotal4" name="hcTotal4" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="hcTotal5" name="hcTotal5" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-2">
              <p class="total">Total Cost of Ownership</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="number" id="TotalCost" name="TotalCost" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!--  <script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".submit").click(function(a){a.preventDefault();var e=$("#msform").serializeArray();$.ajax({url:"send.php",type:"POST",data:e,cache:!1,success:function(a){$(".data").html(a)}})})});</script> -->
</html>
```

Comment: Your most recent edits have been rolled back. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works, but could really do with a big redesign. If you wanted to make a small change to this, it would be a nightmare. I would suggest some sort of for loop and using functions to simplify the code. For example:

```
function update_to_product (inOne, inTwo, out) {
     $(out).val(parseFloat($(inOne).val()) * (parseFloat($(inTwo).val())));
}
```

and then use a for loop to create those IDs programmatically. This will massively reduce the amount of code and make it easier to read.

```
//Make ids (ie in1 = "#1hcc1", in2 = "#1hcq1", out "#1hc1")
update_to_product(in1, in2, out)
```

you can do this for every calculation set.

Comment: With this in mind I did some more studying and have added an updated snippet. I wasn't able to get a change event to work within the for loop of DivBox and ended up repeating the loop in DoDivBox. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Vogon Jeltz, I studied up more on For Loops and Functions and came up with the following revision:

```js
function DivBox( col, row )
{
    var ret = "";
    
    for( var r = 0; r < row ; r++ )
    {
        ret += '<div class="year'+(r+1)+'"><div id="head2" class="head container-fluid row"><h3>Year '+(r+1)+'</h3></div><div class="row table" id="Column'+(r+1)+'" >';
        
        for( var c = 0; c < col; c++ )
        {
                        var idM = (r+1)+"sfm"+(c+1);
                var idA = (r+1)+"sfa"+(c+1);
            
            ret += '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3"><p>Doctor '+(c+1)+'</p></div><div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input type="number" id="'+idM+'" name="'+idM+'" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><p>x12 mo</p></div><div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input type="number" id="'+idA+'" name="'+idA+'" step="0.01" value="" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control"></div></div></div>'; 
        }
        ret += '</div></div>';              
    }
    return ret;
       
}

$(document).on( "ready", function DoDivBox( col, row )
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("SubFees");
    var col = 5;
    var row = 3;
    obj.innerHTML = DivBox( row, col );
    
    $("#SubFees").on("change input keyup", function(){
        for( var r = 0; r <= row ; r++ ) {
        for( var c = 0; c <= col; c++ ) {
         var idM = (c+1)+"sfm"+(r+1);
         var idA = (c+1)+"sfa"+(r+1);
         $("#"+idA).val(parseFloat($("#"+idM).val() * 12).toFixed(2));
      }}})
    
})
```

```css
form {max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<body>
<form>
  <fieldset id="SubFees">
  
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

I couldn't get the change event function to work within the DivBox for loop though so I ended up repeating the for loop in DoDivBox.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas ...

To DRY-off the javascript :

- For efficient selection of DOM elemenmts, in the HTML give a className to each related groups of inputs, eg. "sfm", "sfa", "hcc", "hcq".
- Reduce reliance on IDs.
- Allow the `input` handlers to handle just the triggering change. It's not necessary to perform all related calcs on all occasions. Others will look after themselves if/when they are triggered.
- For each handler, develop an efficient generalized function to express the desired effect.
- Exploit [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum values.

Other considerations :

- Wrap in `jQuery(function($) {...})`
- Attach handlers such that the calculation of totals is performed *after* the intra-row stuff, and calculate the grand total in the same handler.
- Convert string to number, with the syntactically convenient `+foo` instead of `parseFloat(foo)`.
- Set `min="0"` attributes on the inputs to prevent them going negative.
- Javascript functions don't require an explicit `return` unless the caller expects a return value.

I ended up with this :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 // ----- fixed data -----
 var sf = { n:3, els:$('.sfa') },
  hc = { n:4, els:$('.hc') },
  years = 5;

 // ----- utility functions -----
 function sumValues(runningTotal, el) {
  return runningTotal + +el.value;
 }

 /* ------- Subscription Fees ------- */
 $('.sfm').on('input', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').find('input.sfa').val(this.value * 12);
 });
 $('.sfa').on('input', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').find('input.sfm').val(this.value / 12);
 });

 /* ------- Hardware Costs ------- */
 $('.hcc').on('input', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  $row.find('.hc').val(this.value * $row.find('.hcq').val());
 });
 $('.hcq').on('input', function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  $row.find('.hc').val(this.value * $row.find('.hcc').val());
 });

 /* ------- Totals ------- */
 $('#msform input').on('change keyup input', function() {
  var i, t1, t2, total = 0;
  for(i=0; i<years; i++) {
   t1 = sf.els.get().slice(sf.n*i, sf.n*(i+1)).reduce(sumValues, 0).toFixed(2);
   t2 = hc.els.get().slice(hc.n*i, hc.n*(i+1)).reduce(sumValues, 0).toFixed(2);
   $('.sfTotal').eq(i).val(t1); // Subscription Fees
   $('.hcTotal').eq(i).val(t2); // Hardware Costs
   total += +t1;
   total += +t2;
  }
  $('#TotalCost').val(total.toFixed(2));
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form id="msform">
 <fieldset id="table-two" class="table container-fluid">
   <div class="year1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
   <h2 class="fs-title">Subscription Fees</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="head2" class="head">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-3">
    <h3>Monthly Fee</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-3">
    <h3>Annual Spend</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>Year 1</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>1st Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1sfm1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1sfa1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>2nd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1sfm2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1sfa2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>3rd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1sfm3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1sfa4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year2">
  <h4>Year 2</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>1st Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2sfm1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2sfa1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>2nd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2sfm2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2sfa2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>3rd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2sfm3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2sfa3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year3">
  <h4>Year 3</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>1st Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3sfm1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3sfa1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>2nd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3sfm2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3sfa2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>3rd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3sfm3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3sfa3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year4">
  <h4>Year 4</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>1st Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfm1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4sfa1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>2nd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4sfm2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4sfa2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>3rd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4sfm3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4sfa3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year5">
  <h4>Year 5</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>1st Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfm1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfa1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>2nd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfm2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfa2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>3rd Doctor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfm3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfm">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <p>x12 mo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5sfa3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control sfa">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    </fieldset>
 <fieldset id="table-three" class="table container-fluid">
   <div class="year1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
   <h2>Hardware Costs</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="head3" class="head">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-6">
     <h3>Cost/Device</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
     <h3>Quantity</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-1">
     <h3>Annual Spend</h3>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>Year 1</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcq1" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>iPads</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcq2" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Android Tablets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcq3" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Servers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hcq4" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="1hc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year2">
  <h4>Year 2</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcq1" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>iPads</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcq2" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Android Tablets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcq3" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Servers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hcq4" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="2hc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year3">
  <h4>Year 3</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcq1" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>iPads</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcq2" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Android Tablets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcq3" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Servers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hcq4" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="3hc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year4">
  <h4>Year 4</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcq1" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>iPads</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcq2" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Android Tablets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcq3" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Servers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hcq4" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="4hc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="year5">
  <h4>Year 5</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Computers/Laptops</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcq1" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hc1" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>iPads</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcq2" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hc2" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Android Tablets</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcq3" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hc3" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3">
   <p>Servers</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hcc">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">x</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hcq4" min="0" step="1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control hcq">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
   <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
     <input type="number" name="5hc4" min="0" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control hc">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </fieldset>
 
 <fieldset id="table-seven" class="table container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2"> 
    <h3>Year 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <h3>Year 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"> 
    <h3>Year 3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <h3>Year 4</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <h3>Year 5</h3>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <p>Subscription Fees</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="sfTotal1" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control sfTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="sfTotal2" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control sfTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="sfTotal3" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control sfTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="sfTotal4" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control sfTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="sfTotal5" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control sfTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <p>Hardware Costs</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="hcTotal1" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control hcTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="hcTotal2" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control hcTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="hcTotal3" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control hcTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="hcTotal4" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control hcTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" name="hcTotal5" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control hcTotal">
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-2">
    <p class="total">Total Cost of Ownership</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
   <input type="number" id="TotalCost" name="TotalCost" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" readonly class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!--  <script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".submit").click(function(a){a.preventDefault();var e=$("#msform").serializeArray();$.ajax({url:"send.php",type:"POST",data:e,cache:!1,success:function(a){$(".data").html(a)}})})});</script> -->
</html>
```

You might also consider keeping the html DRY by templating/cloning the repeated sections.